# select all the values from one table and some values from another table and display them with php

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am trying to get all the values from one table and some values from another table and display them using php and html. It is a demo point of sale program that I am trying to modify.

The section I am trying to modify is the sales report page, where initially I have  `TRANSACTION ID`, `DATE`, `INVOICE NUMBER`, `AMOUNT` and `REMARKS`. I would like to add some values from another table (i.e. sales "NAME" and "QTY").

Here is what I did:

```
            <?php
                include('../connect.php');
                $d1=$_GET['d1'];
                $d2=$_GET['d2'];
                $result = $db->prepare("SELECT sales.* , sales_order.name, sales_order.qty FROM sales,sales_order WHERE date BETWEEN :a AND :b");
                $result->bindParam(':a', $d1);
                $result->bindParam(':b', $d2);
                $result->execute();
                for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
            ?>
            <tr class="record">
            <td>STI-000<?php echo $row['transaction_id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['invoice_number']; ?></td>
            <tf><?php echo $row{'invoice_number'};?></td>
            <td><?php
            $dsdsd=$row['amount'];
            echo formatMoney($dsdsd, true);
            ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['type']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                }
            ?>

    </tbody>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4" style="border-top:1px solid #999999"> Total </th>
            <th colspan="2" style="border-top:1px solid #999999"> 
            <?php
                function formatMoney($number, $fractional=false) {
                    if ($fractional) {
                        $number = sprintf('%.2f', $number);
                    }
                    while (true) {
                        $replaced = preg_replace('/(-?\d+)(\d\d\d)/', '$1,$2', $number);
                        if ($replaced != $number) {
                            $number = $replaced;
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    return $number;
                }
                $d1=$_GET['d1'];
                $d2=$_GET['d2'];
                $results = $db->prepare("SELECT sum(amount) FROM sales WHERE date BETWEEN :a AND :b");
                $results->bindParam(':a', $d1);
                $results->bindParam(':b', $d2);
                $results->execute();
                for($i=0; $rows = $results->fetch(); $i++){
                $dsdsd=$rows['sum(amount)'];
                echo formatMoney($dsdsd, true);
                }
                ?>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to join the two tables together in one query?

Comment: as per the above, you would need to use a join.  It's difficult to guide you through this without knowing what fields are in the tables, and how (if at all) they are related between the two tables.  Reading up on MySQL joins will help though.

Comment: If you want to join the two tables, you can update your post and give us the structure of the two tables and their relation to one another.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the key linking the tables `sales` and `sales_order` are the field `invoice_number` you have to join the two tables using an INNER JOIN (or a LEFT JOIN depending on your needs) as following :

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT sales.* , sales_order.name, sales_order.qty FROM sales INNER JOIN sales_order ON sales.invoice_number = sales_order.invoice_number WHERE sales.date BETWEEN :a AND :b");
```

If the key linking the two tables is something else, then just update the `ON sales.invoice_number = sales_order.invoice_number` to match the good column name

Also, do not forget to add the name of the table before each fields when you join tables because if you have the same field name in more than one table it will give you an error because mysql won't know in which table it has to get the data from.